# C - Print character '>'

Tags: c

How can i print the special character '>' in C ? It prints an arrow pointed to the left and the character that i add with scanf does print in the right way.

```
int main (int argc, char **argv){
 int i;
 char line[2];
 line[1]=">";
 scanf("%c",&line[2]);
 for(i=1;i<=2;i++)
 printf("%c",&line[i]);
}
```

Comment: This is not Pascal or Delphi :)

Comment: If this code compiled, you need a new compiler.

Comment: What system are you using?  Because `printf(">")` should work.

Comment: Im using Windows 8.1

Answer (score 8):

- C uses zero based indexing. Your code gets that wrong systematically.
- You are passing the address of the character to `printf` rather than the character.
- Use `'` to introduce character literals. You used `"` which introduces C string literals.

Your code should be

```
line[0] = '>';
scanf("%c", &line[1]);
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    printf("%c", line[i]);
```

My final piece of advice is for you to ask your compiler to emit warnings and then take heed of them.

Comment: what about using `'` instead of `"`?

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I missed that one. The DV was a little hasty though, I just needed a second to correct the answer!

Comment: How can i make the line[1] get a string like "text" ?

Comment: `line[1]` is a single character.

Comment: I need to make a string that looks something like ">text" . If i enter '>' on the first position , how can i and on text after it  ? lets say line has 10 positions .

Comment: That's a different question. I cannot answer that in comments to this question. You asked a very specific question which I believe has been answered.

Answer (score 2):

**Your errors:**

1. `scanf("%c",&line[2]);` --> out of bound access [`off-by-one`]. you're trying to access the `3rd` element, which is not there. Always remember, array indexing in `c` starts from 0, i.e., index `n` denotes the `n+1`th element.
2. `printf("%c",&line[i]);` absoluely wrong, maybe you got confused with `scanf()` syantax.
3. `for` loop initialization and condition check.

**The solution**

1. change `line[1]=">";` to `line[0]='>';`
2. change `scanf("%c",&line[2]);` to `scanf(" %c",&line[1]);`
3. change `for(i=1;i<=2;i++)` to `for(i=0;i< 2;i++)`
4. change `printf("%c",&line[i]);` to `printf("%c",line[i]);`

Note: As a good practice, always add the `return` value in `main()`.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer